# Zend Expressive: how to change layout using Zend View

Tags: template-engine, zend-view, mezzio

Zend Expressive defaults to `layout` template when using **Zend View**. I note the `addTemplate($template)` function in **PhpRenderer** class but where and how to add an alternative template to `layout`?

In a middleware factory of an action, in the action itself, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing `layout` key to `render()` method of the renderer in `data` array seems like enough to switch layout just before returning the response.

For example:

```
class HomeAction
{
   public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
   {
     $data = [
        'layout' => 'layout::default',
        // or 'layout::admin',
        // or 'layout::alternative',
     ];

     $body = $this->template->render('app::home', $data);

     return new HtmlResponse($body);
   }
}
```

I strongly recommend watching of repository and it's issue updates on github.

See [#314](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive/issues/314) and [#317](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive/issues/317).